# how to get certain precision values in java?

Tags: java, database

I am passing some values to database(SQL Server) here one of the field contains money type data filed.. while i am passing values for eg:25.21 , in database it was storing 25,2100
Here my question was, i have to show the value in page like 25.21 (only two values after decimalpoint)i have to remove precision values after two decimal. can u send code for that?

Note in java pojo i am using BigDecimal to that property

Comment: `can u send code for that?` You should not have written this

Comment: What page? Would be helpful to have more details.

Comment: float maxval = Float.parseFloat(request.getParameter("maxVal"));obj.setMaxVal(new BigDecimal(minval));

Comment: float maxval = Float.parseFloat(request.getParameter("maxVal"));obj.setMaxVal(new BigDecimal(minval)); this is code for setting to pojo after that it was storing in db; while retrieving i have to show only to values after decimal . i am using jsp page to send & display

Comment: Why some people are too lazy to type `yo` in front of the `u`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you try either DecimalFormat, or String.format or PrintStream.printf depending on what is most appropriate for you. I also suggest you try to accept more answers. ;)

Answer (score 1):

If it is a numeric field in the database, it is not storing it as `21,2500`.  Instead - it is storing it as `21.25`, but the interface that you are using is formatting it for you.  In this case it is showing you 4 digits after the decimal and putting a `,` in for the decimal separator.  I suggest that you do just what your database interface is doing, format the data the way you need it.

See the [JavaDoc for DecimalFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) and the [Java tutorial on custom formats](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html) for some details.